# Is it possible to access the severity of a Security Center recommendation in Azure via Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I want to write a powershell scrip that shows me all the Security Center recommendations in my Azure Account with their severity Level (e.g. Low,Medium or High)
I figured I can use the Az.Security Module to get the Recommendations..(AzSecurityTasks) But I have no idea how to access the severity since the Module doesnt list them for me, I only figured I can access the severity through the az security task list in Azure Cli, but that doesnt help me for my own powershell script. Has anyone an idea? Maybe through a HTTP Request through the Azure Portal or so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of options.

1. You can try to use the API in a PowerShell Script.

When using PowerShell to work with REST APIs, you'll eventually come across two commands: **Invoke-WebRequest** and **Invoke-RestMethod**.

Both of these commands send and receive HTTP data to/from various HTTP endpoints and can be used to interact with REST APIs.

Take a look at this doc for a sample example : [Invoke Rest Method using PS](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2019/04/02/parse-a-rest-api-with-powershell.aspx?m=1#:%7E:text=When%20using%20PowerShell%20to%20work,to%20interact%20with%20REST%20APIs)

To get the security Assessments, call this HTTP Get request in your API method.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments?api-version=2020-01-01
```

Please go through this doc for the sample response and parameter details :
[Assessment List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/assessments/list)

2. Also, have you tried  Get-AzSecurityAssessment cmd using Powershell. It most probably should give you the severity as well.
   Doc reference for [Get-AzSecurityAssessment](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.security/get-azsecurityassessment)

But if it doesn't, please note that the security cmdlets are in preview (not GA) which is probably why you didn't find any docs.
Preview modules don't ship with Az and need to be installed separately:

> Install-Module -Name Az.Security

I hope this information helps.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem differently but the API hint helped me get into that a bit, and so I learned a lot new stuff, which is excellent for me as a beginner and exactly what I want.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear the issue is resolved for you. Please take a moment to "Accept as Answer" and "Upvote" the same as it would benefit the community members.

Comment: Sadly cant upvote since im new on Stack overflow and dont have enough reputation for that..but I Accepted as Answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Severity is part of the assessment metadata resource which is available via API.
Use that instead of the ‘Tasks’ API.

Answer (score 0):

GET [https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments?api-version=2020-01-01](https://management.azure.com/%7Bscope%7D/providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments?api-version=2020-01-01)

it only returns 1000 records.
You then need to take nextLink column to continue with next 1000 records, etc.

Get-AzSecurityAssessment
returns displayname,
but does not return status.code (Healthy, Unhealthy, NotApplicable).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but in case someone still needs it. This helps you also extract the status code:

```
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
$Report = @()
$i = 1
$total = $Subscriptions.count
foreach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions)
    {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $($subscription.id)
    Write-Host "($i out of $total) Processing subscription $($subscription.name)"
    $SecurityAssessments = $null
    $SecurityAssessments = Get-AzSecurityAssessment

    foreach ($SecurityAssessment in $SecurityAssessments)
        {
        $TempEntry = $null
        $TempEntry = $SecurityAssessment | Select-Object Name,DisplayName,Id,
                @{Name="SubscriptionName"; Expression={$($subscription.name)}},
                @{Name="StatusCause"; Expression={$($_.status.cause)}},
                @{Name="StatusCode"; Expression={$($_.status.code)}},
                @{Name="StatusDescription"; Expression={$($_.status.description)}},
                @{Name="ResourceDetailsId"; Expression={$($_.ResourceDetails.Id)}},
                @{Name="ResourceDetailsSource"; Expression={$($_.ResourceDetails.Source)}}
        $Report += $TempEntry
        }
    $i++
    }

$Report
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**